amazon-cognito-identity-js - updateAttributes says "User is not authenticated"
Once a user is authenticated with user.authenticateUser(authDetails);, updating attributes with user.updateAttributes returns the following error:
Error: User is not authenticated
at CognitoUser.updateAttributes (CognitoUser.js:1009)
Solve:
I found the issue. You need to call getSession for the user and perform the update operation inside it. For example:
user?.getSession((err: Error, session: CognitoUserSession | null) => {
  if (err) {
    console.error("Get session failed", err);
    return;
  }

  user?.updateAttributes(attributeList, (err, result) => {
    if (err) {
      console.error("Update attributes failed", err);
      return;
    }

    console.log("Update attributes success", result);
  });
});

